# What happen to Roxie LS?

Tags: pop, indie, songwriter, where-are-they-now

So, yeah, what happened to Roxie LS? I like her style and voice. She was supposed to be big.

She studied classical music, she is British if I remember correctly. She loved surf culture and she surfs (Roxie LS is Roxie Loves Surf). Originally she was a Youtube hype and I thought she is definetelly going to sign on a label. But her youtube account got erased a couple years back and a new one appeared containg only her biggest hit "He's the One".

Where is this girl?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SS2mby7A5js

Comment: Her vimeo channel is still active : https://vimeo.com/59481900

Answer (score 1):

Bit of deeper googling reveals her real name is Samantha Del Greco - sometimes Zola Del Greco, Sophia Del. Hope that helps.

Comment: Some sources or links maybe? I did't find any relations between these names and Roxie LS.

Comment: The face of the person in the youtube account picture looks similar to the model Samantha Del Greco, but the biog doesn't seem to fit. I would need more info to be convinced of this.

Comment: Some newspaper articles from a  [Somerset local paper](http://www.somersetlive.co.uk/mum-s-word-miss-bath-samantha/story-11338825-detail/story.html) fill in elements of S Del G's past : modelling, studying music etc, which sort of fit with the  biog in this article about RLS, here [cooler magazine](https://coolerlifestyle.com/features/this-is-me-roxie-ls.html)  The violinist in [this online directory](http://maslink.co.uk/client-directory?client=DELGS1&) does look like the picture in the cooler magazine link above. So, based on the above, I'd say that S del G probably is Roxie LS

Answer (score 0):

Roxie is Sam Del Greco, I know her. Unfortunately due to a truly awful manager, her situation was made very hard for her and it destroyed her music career.

Comment: Are there any articles or such that you could point readers to? Or maybe add some more detail about what the problems were?